# Using ppois in r to calculate probabilities of random variable with variance

Tags: r, poisson-distribution

I'm working on a homework assignment on little sleep and hoping for some help.  Here is the question I'm trying to write a script for:

Write a script in R to compute the following probabilities of a random variable that has Poisson Distribution with variance 16.

a) is less than 9

What I have is:

```
ppois(9, 16)
```

I know this is incorrect, however cannot think on how to correct the formula to get the mean from the variance.

Comment: Hi, this is not a great SO question because it's not about code but about **knowing the relationship between the mean and the variance in a poisson distribution** which is very specific but I'm not going to say because I'm a professor and you are doing homework.  Still you could Google it or look in any stats book.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your comment @Elin; OP clearly includes a *code attempt*, which makes this a coding question. From his code attempt I infer that he also seems to be clear on the variance-mean relationship of the Poisson distribution (he sets `lambda = 16` in `ppois`).

Comment: "how to correct the formula to get the mean from the variance." ?  Maybe I'm reading it wrong?

Comment: I *think* OP is confused about the definition of the distribution function: `F(x <= x)` vs. `F(X < x)`. He was just looking in the wrong place. But I admit, perhaps I'm wrong. In any case, I think the downvotes are a bit harsh here. OP is a first time SO poster, he includes a clear problem statement, openly and clearly flags his question as homework, and includes a code attempt. That's more than I see with 90% of first-time posters.

Comment: @RonakShah I already put that as a close reason ... but yes I also agree that there is a decent attempt here.

Comment: Thank you all for being gentle.  I'm struggling to grasp a few of these concepts regarding probability while also learning r.  Appreciate the guidance.  Will move to stats for any additional questions not code related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close, barring a small but important detail involving *discrete* distributions.

For discrete distributions the cumulative distribution function is defined as

```
F(x) = Pr(X ≤ x)
```

(note the "less than or equal" sign).

So, in order to get the probability of observing values less than 9 we need to calculate

```
F(8) = Pr(X ≤ 8)
```

which is

```
ppois(8, lambda = 16)
#[1] 0.02198725
```

---

It's instructive to compare this number with a simulation-type experiment, where we draw `N` random numbers from a Poisson distribution with `lambda = 16`.

```
set.seed(2019)
N <- 10^7
x <- rpois(N, lambda = 16)
```

The probability of observing a number less than 9 is then

```
sum(x < 9) / length(x)
#[1] 0.0219958
```

which is very close to the theoretical value.

Comment: Thank you @Maurits for your help!  It's difficult to find help on writing r code AND understanding the math when my confidence in both is minuscule...and I'm on 3 hours sleep!

Comment: @MattBlack I think you could rewrite the  question a bit to make it more clearly lead to this answer if this was what you were looking for.

Comment: @Elin Will ensure my questions are more succinct and reduce noise. Appreciate the  feedback.

Comment: Glad it was helpful @MattBlack and good luck with your studies. If this answers your question please remember to close the question by setting the green check mark next to the answer. That way you keep SO tidy and help future SO users to identify relevant questions. It also grants a small reputation bonus to both the original poster and answerer.

Comment: Done and done @MauritsEvers!  Really appreciate your time and tutelage.

Comment: You're very welcome @MattBlack